# using expo filesystem download pdf

Tags: react-native, expo

im trying to download the pdf file to the local file system ,when i press download icon it console los file downloaded and it shows file path but when i open the particular folder there is no pdf file.

```
 const downloadFile = async (url, name) => {
const downloadDirectory = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}Download/`;

// Create the directory if it doesn't exist
await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(downloadDirectory, {
  intermediates: true,
});

const fileUri = `${downloadDirectory}${name}.pdf`;
const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
  url,
  fileUri
);

try {
  const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
  console.log("Downloaded file uri", uri);
  alert("File downloaded successfully");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

};

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => downloadFile(item.url, item.name)}>
            <AntDesign
              name="download"
              size={24}
              color="black"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```